# Quick sort in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Does this code show proper implementation of quick sort algorithm? If not, why? Can this code further be improved?

```
<?php

$unsorted = range(1,20);
shuffle($unsorted);

function quick_sort($array)
{
    // find array size
    $length = count($array);

    // base case test, if array of length 0 then just return array
    if($length <= 1){

        return $array;
    }
    else{

        // select random element as pivot
        $rand = rand(0,$length-1);
        $pivot = $array[$rand];

        // create two partitions
        $left = $right = array();

        // place elements around pivot by comparison
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            if($i==$rand)continue;

            if($array[$i] < $pivot){
                $left[] = $array[$i];
            }
            else{
                $right[] = $array[$i];
            }
        }

        // recurse
        return array_merge(quick_sort($left), array($pivot), quick_sort($right));
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($unsorted);
print_r(quick_sort($unsorted));

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` statement for array length check is superfluous. Also, your pivot choosing policy has a flaw: on already sorted array it will degrade to quadratic running time; I suggest you choose the pivot randomly or choose the pivot from several elements.

You don't need to do that array creation stuff you seem to do: quicksort can be implemented in-place.